# How to mirror directories using Bitvise sftpc.exe

Tags: ssh, sftp

The Bitvise SSH Client [version history](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-version-history-8) states that v8.15 supports directory mirroring:

> The graphical SSH Client and sftpc now support recursive directory mirroring. A directory and all of its subdirectories and files can be synchronized either in the upload or download direction.

I can find it in the GUI, but I can't find how to do using sftpc.exe. There is no mention of mirroring in `sftpc.exe -help`.

How can I do directory mirroring from the command line?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You point out a tangential design issue in sftpc: getting help for SFTP commands requires you to use sftpc interactively and connect to the server. You can then get help from the interactive prompt.

This is inconvenient, so I opened a feature request for us to make the interactive help available from the command line, as well.

The help text you are looking for is as follows - for the `put` command:

```
sftp> help put
USAGE: put local-path [remote-path] [-bg | -fg] [-s] [-o] [-r]
           [-f] [-noTime] [-m=mode] [-dm=mode] [-mirror [-erase]]
           [-b | -lf | -std | -tlf | -t]
DESCRIPTION: Upload file.
PARAMETERS:
 -bg      Start (queue) upload in background.
 -fg      Start upload in foreground.
 -s       Include subdirectories (recursive).
 -r       Synchronize file content. If synchronization is not available,
          resume existing incomplete files using a heuristic resume.
          Heuristic resume MAY result in an inconsistent destination file
          if the destination file content has been modified in the middle.
 -o       Synchronize file content. If synchronization is not available,
          force existing file to be overwritten. If -r is also specified,
          heuristic resume is tried first.
 -del     Remove local file after successful upload.
 -f       Assume remote-path is a file (not a directory)
 -noTime  Do not synchronize file modification times.
 -m=mode  Set the access mode for remote files to 'mode'.
 -dm=mode Set the access mode for new remote directories to 'mode'.
          If directory already exists, access mode will not be changed.
 -mirror  Mirror local-path to remote-path. Local files that do not exist
          remotely will be uploaded. Remote files that are different than
          their local versions will be overwritten.
 -erase   With -mirror, erase remote files that are not present locally.

FILE TRANSFER MODE - if present, overrides mode selected with "type":
 -b       Upload files as binary; no conversions.
 -lf      Auto-detect text files. In text files, replace CRLF with LF.
          Binary files are unaffected.
 -std     Auto-detect text files. Upload text files using the SFTP v4+ text
          file transfer mechanism. Binary files are unaffected. Not
          available when SFTP version 3 or lower is in use.
 -tlf     Upload all files as textual. Replace all CRLF bytes with LF.
 -t       Upload all files using the SFTP v4+ text file transfer mechanism.
          Not available when SFTP version 3 or lower is in use.
```

And for the `get` command:

```
sftp> help get
USAGE: get remote-path [local-path] [-bg | -fg] [-s] [-o] [-r]
           [-f] [-noTime] [-lit] [-mirror [-erase]]
           [-b | -lf | -std | -tlf | -t]
DESCRIPTION: Download file.
PARAMETERS:
 -bg     Start (queue) download in background.
 -fg     Start download in foreground.
 -s      Include subdirectories (recursive).
 -r      Synchronize file content. If synchronization is not available,
         resume existing incomplete files using a heuristic resume.
         Heuristic resume MAY result in an inconsistent destination file
         if the destination file content has been modified in the middle.
 -o      Synchronize file content. If synchronization is not available,
         force existing file to be overwritten. If -r is also specified,
         heuristic resume is tried first.
 -del    Remove remote file after successful download.
 -f      Assume remote-path is a file (not a directory).
 -noTime Do not synchronize file modification times.
 -lit    Treat remote-path literally (not a wildcard pattern).
 -mirror Mirror remote-path to local-path. Remote files that do not exist
         locally will be downloaded. Local files that are different than
         their remote versions will be overwritten.
 -erase  With -mirror, erase local files that are not present remotely.

FILE TRANSFER MODE - if present, overrides mode selected with "type":
 -b      Download files as binary; no conversions.
 -lf     Auto-detect text files. In text files, replace LF with CRLF.
         Binary files are unaffected.
 -std    Behaves same as -lf when downloading. Not available when SFTP
         version 3 or lower is in use.
 -tlf    Download all files as textual. Replace all LF bytes with CRLF.
 -t      Download all files using the SFTP v4 text file transfer mechanism.
         Not available when SFTP version 3 or lower is in use.
```

I hope this helps!

I don't normally monitor Stack Overflow, so please feel free to call my attention by opening a support case with Bitvise if you need me to look at something else.

I recommend also using the latest Bitvise SSH Client version. Currently, this is 8.35. It's free of charge for use in any environment, and we try to ensure that each version is a strict upgrade that does not introduce new difficulties. We want there to be no reason to stay behind. :-)

Comment: Thanks Denis. That helps a lot. Unfortunately I have a followup question :)

When doing a mirror, what's the rule to determine if local and remote files are the same or different? I'm doing a ```put -mirror``` from Win10 to Debian. sftpc uploads *every* file *every* time. It never determines that the files are the same, even when calling the command twice back-to-back.

Comment: -mirror tries to ensure the result is correct. It prefers to synchronize using SFTP v6 block-by-block hashing functionality. However, in the 2000s, OpenSSH decided "640 kB ought to be enough for anyone", and they're not going to implement SFTP beyond v3. So OpenSSH lacks SFTP v6 file hashing. In this case, when using -mirror, the SSH Client overwrites because there's no way to verify if remote files contain changes in the middle. Heuristic resume *could* be supported, but is not because it can result in invisible corruption on large directory trees which are the intended use case with -mirror.

Comment: That's a pity. I'll have to cobble together my own sync routine based on timestamps. :/ Thanks for your help though!